# Hide bottom line in RAF (Roku Advertising Framework)

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am creating my own channel for Roku and use RAF for ads, before starting ads show loading bar and text **"Your program will begin after this message"**  i want to Remove this message and loading bar. How to add custom text and loader for ads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is listed everything you can customize in RAF's buffering screen:
https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Roku+Advertising+Framework#RokuAdvertisingFramework-BufferScreenCustomization

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with:

```
adIface.enableAdBufferMessaging(false,false)
```

The first argument is enableMsg and it's used to enable/disable adBuffering Screen message.
The second argument is enableProgressBar and it's used to enable/disable progress Bar on adBuffering Screen.

More info on this [here](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Integrating+the+Roku+Advertising+Framework).